# How to achieve "scheduling" in Google App Engine

Tags: java, multithreading, google-app-engine, scheduling

Know that either java-version or python-version it doesn't support threading or processes. So if I want to execute a small snippet periodically in GAE, is there any possibility?

Oh, I'm just finding there is a document mentioned about it:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron.html

Comment: Yes, they weren't avaiable in the early versions of the platform but were added later (and it was definitely a feature that a lot of developers wanted). By the way, when you answer your own question I think the convention is actually to post an answer -- which you can then accept. Otherwise, the question will display as "unanswered".

Comment: almost a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276984/gwt-google-app-engine-timertask-or-thread-in-serviceimpl-throw-exception/1277502#1277502

Answer (score 1):

I hate to [Necromance](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/17/necromancer) this question but it showed up on the first page of search results, so... it may be that the [Task Queue](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) (which is currently experimental) may be a good fit for simulating multitasking beyond just cron jobs. You can currently have up to 10 separate queues with up to 20 executions per second, so theoretically you could execute 200 "threads" per second.

Most interesting (to me, anyway) is the bucket size parameter of the [queue configuration](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/queue.html), which uses a "token bucket" algorithm to allow usage spikes. Neat stuff.