# Timer replacement for Appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, timer

I am working on an GWT Appenginge project. I get my data from an external api and i want to update the database every minute. I just found out that appengine does not allow timers! Why??
What workarounds are there, or do you think i have a general design flaw.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for something similar to this: [GWT, Google App Engine, TimerTask or Thread in ServiceImpl throw exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276984/gwt-google-app-engine-timertask-or-thread-in-serviceimpl-throw-exception)

Also, you might want to update your question title - it doesn't seem to be related to your question.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried an App Engine cron task?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question as asked:

> I just found out that appengine does not allow timers! Why??

java.util.Timer is implemented using a Thread, which AppEngine does not allow except using its own API. So when you try to use java.util.Timer, you get an exception:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:375)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:565)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(CustomSecurityManager.java:56)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.CustomSecurityManager.checkAccess(CustomSecurityManager.java:131)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.checkAccess(ThreadGroup.java:315)
    at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:378)
    at java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:432)
    at java.util.TimerThread.<init>(Timer.java:499)
    at java.util.Timer.<init>(Timer.java:101)
    at java.util.Timer.<init>(Timer.java:132)
```

Disallowing arbitrary thread creation makes it easier for the AppEngine system to manage multiple applications on the same machine without interfering with each other too much.

AppEngine is offering a new service called "Managed VMs" which will allow any environment you want, including a full JVM that can have background threads:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/

Note that this API is currently in "preview" which means it is not yet recommended for reliable production use.